# CameraX | Enable/Disable image analysis

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm trying to implement barcode scanner using CameraX and ZXing barcode scanning library.

I've wrote a custom Analyzer that decodes barcodes and those barcodes should be processed (processing logic obviously takes some time).

So what I want is to disable image analysis on the fly and enable it again if the result of the processing operation wasn't successful.

My base setup logic:

```
    private fun setupCamera() {
        processCameraProvider.unbindAll()
        val camera = processCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            this,
            CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
            buildPreviewUseCase(),
            buildImageAnalysisUseCase())
    }

    private fun buildPreviewUseCase(): Preview {
        return Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(cameraPreview.display.rotation)
            .build()
            .apply {
                previewSurfaceProvider = cameraPreview.previewSurfaceProvider
            }
    }

    private fun buildImageAnalysisUseCase(): ImageAnalysis {
        return ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(cameraPreview.display.rotation)
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build()
            .apply {
                setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
                    ZxingBarcodeAnalyzer { qrResult ->
                        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                            viewModel.handleBarcode(qrResult.text)
                        }
                    })
            }
    }
```

After digging around the library sources I'm still don’t understand how I can achieve desired behaviour?

If I call `unbind(imageAnalysisUseCase object)` on the `processCameraProvider` I can't bind that object again (`processCameraProvider` has only `bindToLifecycle()` method, not `bind(imageAnalysisUseCase object)`).

Calling `clearAnalyzer()` on the `ImageAnalysis` resets image analysis completely despite calling `setAnalyzer()` again.

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: @c0nst, did you found the solution? Same goal here.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the producer to produce one image at a time, until you close the proxy.

```
ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = imageAnalysisBuilder.setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_BLOCK_PRODUCER).setImageQueueDepth(1).build();
```

From the docs,
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis#STRATEGY_BLOCK_PRODUCER

> Block the producer from generating new images.
>
> Once the producer has produced the number of images equal to the image
> queue depth, and none have been closed, the producer will stop
> producing images. Note that images may be queued internally and not be
> delivered to the analyzer until the last delivered image has been
> closed with ImageProxy.close()

Comment: Let's say I'd like to stop analysis for 10 seconds but then continue as normal, how could I implement your solution? Thank you

Comment: This piece of code fixed my problem. The preview paused until you manually call `imageProxy.close()`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

there is a issue with the `clearAnalyzer()`

I'm using like this until is fix :

```
  fun enableAnalysis(enable: Boolean) {
    if (!enable) {
        isAnalyzerSet = false
        imageAnalysisUseCase?.clearAnalyzer()
        imageAnalysisUseCase.setAnalyzer(analysisExecutor, ImageAnalysis.Analyzer { })

    } else {
        if (isAnalyzerSet) return
        isAnalyzerSet = true
        imageAnalysisUseCase?.setAnalyzer(analysisExecutor, analyzer)
    }
}
```

Comment: In which version is the issue?

Comment: I had the same issue with restarting analyzer, which did not work. My problem was, that I did not do imageProxy.close()

Comment: Can you explain code a bit what are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is not process any images while an image is being processed, you can set a tag inside the analysis method that returns immediately if an image is being processed. Something like this:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private var isProcessing = false

    fun handleBarcode(text: String) {
        if (isProcessing) {
            return
        }
        // Do your processing here.
    }
}
```

If you call `processCameraProvider.unbind(imageAnalysis)`, you can bind the use case again by calling `processCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(, , imageAnalysis)` using the same instance, but I'm not sure if this would work. Re-binding the same Preview use case instance doesn't work, I'm not sure if the rule applies to ImageAnalysis.